# shall vs should

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs

This question is not a duplicate of:

- [How to choose between shall and should?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65893/how-to-choose-between-shall-and-should)
- [Modal verbs in reported speech](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13370/modal-verbs-in-reported-speech)
- [Usage of 'shall' in questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22651/usage-of-shall-in-questions)

because it provides detailed dictionary definitions, reveals a likely
contradiction in the strength of these two words, and covers usage scenarios
that are not addressed by those questions.

---

The definitions of *shall* and *should* confused me. It seems that *shall* can
be either stronger or weaker than *should*.

### Case 1: shall < should

- shall:

  - modal verb (SUGGEST)

    used, with "I" or "we", to make a suggestion:

    > Shall I call him tomorrow?
- should:

  - modal verb (DUTY)

    used to say or ask what is the correct or best thing to do:

    > Should I apologize to him?

### Case 2: shall > should

- shall:

  - modal verb (CERTAINLY WILL)

    used to say that something certainly will or must happen, or that you
    are determined that something will happen:

    > You shall go to the ball, Cinderella.
- should:

  - modal verb (PROBABLE)

    used to show when something is likely or expected:

    > You should find this guidebook helpful.

---

So if two senior people (for example, a *shall* boss and a *should* boss) tell me:

- *You shall do something.* and *You should do something.*, or
- *The work shall be done tomorrow.* and *The work should be done tomorrow.*

How can I tell who has a stronger will?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it clearly states in the definitions that you provide, **shall** used to **SUGGEST** something is only used with I/we:

> shall I call him tomorrow? - *suggestion*

So, in the shall/should boss sentences, **shall** can only mean **CERTAINLY WILL**. Context would dictate whether **should** means **DUTY** or **PROBABLE**, but whatever the meaning, it is weaker than **CERTAINLY WILL**.

The **shall** boss is the tough cookie.

Comment: So *You shall* is always strong and *Shall you* is never used?

Comment: @Cyker. Check out this NGram, **shall you** does occur, but not in modern usage to make a suggestion.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shall+you%2C+shall+I%2C+shall+we&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshall%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshall%20I%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshall%20we%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you find seemingly contradictory definitions should tell you that you're probably misinterpreting the data.  *Shall* has a number of uses, mostly to imply an order or a requirement.

> You **shall** write your grandmother a thank-you note. (I'm telling you to do this)

*Should* has a number of uses, mostly to imply an expectation or a possibility.

> You **should** write your grandmother a thank-you note. (it's the expected thing to do).

There are other uses.  In a question, both can express *invitation* or *suggestion*.  In this case *shall* is slightly more formal, and possibly more common in certain dialects:

> **Shall/Should** we go join our friends?
>
> What **shall/should** we order for dinner?

In any case, if your boss tells you *shall* do something, take it as a direct order.  If they instead say you *should* do something, treat it as an expectation. Naturally, the "strength" of these depends on context.  Some bosses like to make suggestions rather than give orders, but that doesn't mean you are free to ignore them.